# Cart showing empty in safari only in ipad

Tags: cart, session, cookie

We are using magento 1.5.1.0, In ipad - selected item not showing in cart when using safari browser.

Please help us how to solve it.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: please check your cookie setting at safari